# Awk exchange values from different columns

Tags: arrays, bash, awk

I have a file of the following structure:

```
4 1:4 3:1 6:1 56:2 57:4 58:7 59:1 66:2
1 2:1 56:1 57:1 58:2 59:2 65:1
8 1:2 2:1 3:8 12:1 56:1 57:2 58:2 59:2 66:1 67:2
```

What I need to do is to switch the values associated with 56 and 57 to the ones associated with 58 and 59:

```
4 1:4 3:1 6:1 56:7 57:1 58:2 59:4 66:2
1 2:1 56:2 57:2 58:1 59:1 65:1
8 1:2 2:1 3:8 12:1 56:2 57:2 58:1 59:2 66:1 67:2
```

For now I am trying to perform the replacement with at least two columns using something like:

```
awk '{
         for ( i=2;i<=NF;i++ )
         {
            split(, a, ":") 
            arr[a[1]] = a[2]
         }
      }
      END {
         n = asorti(arr, dest)
         ORS= 
         for ( i=1; i<=n; i++ ) 
         { 
            if ( dest[i] != 56 && dest[i] != 58 ) 
               print dest[i] ":" arr[dest[i]]
            else 
            { 
               if ( dest[i] == 56 ) 
                  print dest[i] ":" arr[dest[i+2]] 
               if ( dest[i] == 58 ) 
                  print dest[i] ":" arr[dest[i-2]]
            }
         }
      }' file
```

However, that looks quite bulky and final indexes are not sorted properly.
Will appreciate any other solution.

Comment: Do 56, 57, 58 and 59 always appear in that order on every line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can rely on the ordering always being 56, 57, 58, 59, then you can do this with sed:

```
sed -E 's/(56:)([0-9]+)(.*57:)([0-9]+)(.*58:)([0-9]+)(.*59:)([0-9]+)/\1\6\3\8\5\2\7\4/' file
```

Just capture all the parts and reshuffle them in the replacement.

The odd-numbered capture groups refer to the "labels" and any leading content, except for in the first case where we don't have to touch that part of the line. The even-numbered ones refer to the numerical values.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. That was an example-file, I should check if I can use something similar with the files of different values to replace.

Comment: It's fine to post an example file as long as it is representative of your real file. If that's not the case, you should update your question to provide us with something more realistic.

Answer (score 1):

GNU **`awk`** solution:

```
awk '{ 
         r=gensub(/\<(56:)([0-9]+) (57:)([0-9]+) (58:)([0-9]+) (59:)([0-9]+)/, 
                 "\\1\\6 \\3\\8 \\5\\2 \\7\\4", "g"); 
         print r 
     }' file
```

The output:

```
4 1:4 3:1 6:1 56:7 57:1 58:2 59:4 66:2
1 2:1 56:2 57:2 58:1 59:1 65:1
8 1:2 2:1 3:8 12:1 56:2 57:2 58:1 59:2 66:1 67:2
```

---

> **`gensub(regexp, replacement, how [, target])`**
>
> Search the target string `target` for matches of the regular
>   expression `regexp`. If `how` is a string beginning with ‘`g`’ or ‘`G`’
>   (short for “*global*”), then replace all matches of `regexp` with
>   `replacement`.